# Increase Java’s maximum heap size when using “make” command

Tags: java, android, 17.10, make, openjdk

**I'm working with Android-x86, but the problem I have is with make command, not Android.**

I'm trying to compile Android-x86 Oreo as `android_x86_64-userdebug` using `m -j2 iso_img`, and I'm stuck in a loop. While compiling using java, it gave a common error, "Out of memory error". Well, I know I can use `java -Xmx512m -Xms512m [jar, class, whatever]`, but since I’m using make command, I can't pass these arguments directly. What I did was to run `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx512m -Xms512m"` so it was going to include these options as well. **It didn't.** It changed absolutely **NOTHING.** I tried several times, but nothing changes.

***So, my question is:***
How can I pass a maximum heap size for java while using `make` command?
*I’m sorry if it’s the wrong site to ask this.*

Comment: Edit the `Makefile`

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I have already fixed my problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to fix it myself. For those who are having the same problem, here is my fix:

Let’s say your normal command is:

```
make -j2 OUT_DIR=/path/to/some/dir
```

At the end of the command, add a space than add `JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m`, for example:

```
make -j2 OUT_DIR=/path/to/some/dir JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
```

You have to change **1024** to your desired maximum heap size in Megabytes. Hope this helps!